# Opening multiple hyperlinks in VBA in separate tabs

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I've found many different solutions for this issue, but here's the best code I've found so far:

```
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that this opens all of the hyperlinks in the same tab, so that I only get the last page loaded. What I want is all of the links displayed in separate tabs. How can I modify this to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA, Excel 2010, open internet explore in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386091/vba-excel-2010-open-internet-explore-in-new-tab)

Comment: Instead of doing hyperlink `.Follow` method, get an explicit handle on the browser (presumably IE as default) and have the browser `.Navigate` to the `xHyperlink.Address` using the method in the other answer.

Comment: I have no idea why, but when I opened a new window in Firefox then tried to run the code again, it worked just fine, opening each hyperlink in a new tab. So actually the code works fine as is. Previously I tried to open it in an existing window which already had some tabs open

Comment: Works in Chrome too.

Comment: Yeah it's nice that it uses whatever your current open browser is, before I found this solution I was trying to use IE automation. I hate IE automation.

Comment: Update: I haven't been able to get this code to work recently. As a result I've posted an answer that works consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I finally found a better solution: Just use Wscript.

```
Sub OpenDemLinksBoi()
    Dim SelecRng As Range

    Set SelecRng = Application.Selection
    Set SelecRng = Application.InputBox("Range", SelecRng, Type:=8)

    For Each Cell In SelecRng
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 'I think this basically allows you to input shell commands, hence the "Run" in the next line, which functions exactly like Run. Test it out, try putting a link_
    'into Run and see what happens. Same thing as this script.
    objShell.Run (Cell)
    Next

End Sub
```